# Amazon Alexa offline text retrieval

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My plan is to built a smart home application, that uses OpenAI's GPT-4 to handle all natural language inputs. As a Speech-to-text device i would like to use the Amazon Echo, as it's able to recognize the wake word very well.

As I've never worked with the Echo, I couldnt figure out a way to just retrive the literal plain text. Is the a way to do this, without distributing a skill and without requiring internet connection?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For Smart Home Skill type, Alexa uses Amazon built interaction model so there is no way to retrieve utterances from users. Alexa will send you requests depending on What a user asks.

For Custom Skill type, you can use [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#searchquery) slot type to retrieve user's utterance. However it requires "a carrier phrase", which is the word or words that are part of the utterance, but not the slot, such as "search for" or "find out". At this point, there is no way to retrieve user's utterance as literal plain text.

Both skill type, you need to get requests, and slots via internet. There is no way to directly retrieve them from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the official way to do this is to have a slot of type `AMAZON.SearchQuery`, which captures pretty much everything the user says into the slot value. The only gotcha is that `AMAZON.SearchQuery` requires at least one anchor word to be in the utterance. E.g., you must have something like "I think {searchQuerySlot}" or "consider {searchQuerySlot}". You can't have the slot in the utterance by itself...in other words an utterance like "{searchQuerySlot}" is not allowed.

It's a little bit dated, but I created a video several months ago at https://youtu.be/4g_rY451bxM that shows how this works. (I really need to create an updated video, to show new stuff I've figured out since then.)

That said, I've seen developers use a different slot type such as `AMAZON.Book` or `AMAZON.Movie` instead of `AMAZON.SearchQuery`. These slot types allow a fairly broad selection of words (because books and movies could have almost any words in their title) and they do not require an anchor word. That said, this is a hack, may not work perfectly, and is a misuse of those slot types which may be problematic when you try to certify your skill for publication.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack this to some degree with the `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot type, but unless you're in a real hurry, you probably want to wait for the recently announced LLM centric ASK development changes. Those will let you use Alexa's LLM to do the natural language processing, without incurring additional latency from bouncing around multiple backends, and without the additional cost of calling an LLM yourself.

Here's a blog post from the announcement with more information: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2023/09/alexa-llm-fall-devices-services-sep-2023

Whether you'll ever be able to do that while your Alexa device has no internet connection though, is unclear. At present, some Alexa devices have limited offline capabilities, but those don't provide what you're describing.